# value from edit text as a time value to save in sharedpreferences and show that time in list view

Tags: android

How to get value from edit text as a time value to save it in shared preferences  to change the profile to silent at that specific time   and how to show that time in list view.` Button AddTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddTime);

```
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Stime))
    {
        stime.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Stime, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Etime)) {
        etime.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Etime, ""));
    }
    stime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stime);

    stime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Process to get Current Time
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(TimeBased.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    stime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    stime   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.stime);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });

    etime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etime);

    etime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Process to get Current Time
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(TimeBased.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    etime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    etime   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etime);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });


    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addtlist);


    // ArrayList for data row
    alist = new ArrayList<>();
    // SimpleAdapter mapping static data to views in xml file
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, alist, R.layout.row, new String[]{"lst", "let"}, new int[]{R.id.lst, R.id.let});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    AddTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // HashMap for data values of each row
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("lst", stime.getText().toString());
            map.put("let", etime.getText().toString());
            alist.add(map);
            // Notify the ListView of data changed
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(TimeBased.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alist.remove(positionToRemove);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});
            adb.show();
        }
    });

    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            savePreferences();
            TimeBased.this.setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TimeBased.this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this can truly be a downvoted question !

Anyway, if i were you:

- Do not use EditText to let user input date values, you will never have two persons using the same pattern
- Use a DialogTimePicker AND display the result in a TextView if you want, clicking that TextView triggers the popup
- Now you do have, for sure, a valid Date, convert it to a long value using getTime() and put that long in your preferences

For the example, here is what i'm using

```
public void openDateDialog() {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            if (datePicker.isShown()) {
                //here create your date object with year, month and day and save getTime() to prefs
            }
        }
    };

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, 2000, 5, 5);
    dialog.setTitle("your title here");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: plz some more help about how to show that time in listview for editing/deleting because I want to add time intervals to apply profile silent for that time interval.

Comment: If you are sure that you will have to scroll through a lot of times input, then look at the "view holder pattern". You have a lot a example on internet and here on SO. But if you don't have too much, no need to overkill it, a simple linear layout will perform well. How many items are we taking about?